# How is dot notation implemented in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas DataFrame, you can get/set existing column data by simply using:

```
df.column_name
```

Understandably, it has limitations (restrictions on names, doesn't work if column doesn't exist).

How do they actually implement this? I was expecting them to use `__getattr__` and `__setattribute__`, but I don't see that in pandas.core.frame.py. It seems to pass through the `query` method, but beyond that I can't figure it out.

I have interest in doing something like this for my own application, and I really hate using `__getattr__` and `__setattribute__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit more digging and found the answer in `generic.py`: it indeed uses `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, name: str):
    """After regular attribute access, try looking up the name
    This allows simpler access to columns for interactive use.
    """

def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:
    """After regular attribute access, try setting the name
    This allows simpler access to columns for interactive use.
    """
```

It functions as you might expect - it checks the attribute name against the DataFrame column names to decide what to do.